# Term for a person who dreams or imagines events that later take place

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for a person who has dreams or thoughts that later in life become reality?

Comment: Trouble is, they only get labelled as ???? retrospectively...At the time of those person's dreams, that's all he is - a dreamer!

Answer (score 14):

The word is prescient. "He shared a prescient warning."

or

"He was prescient in his prediction."

Comment: This describes the warning itself, not the person giving it.

Comment: It's not clear whether the question is after a noun or an adjective. "Prescient" is an adjective. It has started to be used of a person exhibiting prescience, eg "I was prescient...".

Answer (score 6):

Precognition: "related to an event that has not yet happened." MW. In Minority Report, the people who could do this were called "precogs." The precognition of the event prevented it from happening, if Tom Cruise was on the ball.

Comment: "Precognition" is the name of a process not the person. "Precog" is a derived word, but as far as I am aware, used only in SFF literature.

Comment: @Francis Yes, precognitive is the adjective. "My precognitive son predicted  the accident." "She is precognitive." "She as a precognitive."?

Answer (score 6):

A few to choose from: prophet, clairvoyant, seer, psychic, oracle.

Comment: A psychic might have other powers (telekinesis, ESP) that were not predictive in nature.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean in the context of it being supernatural, i.e. not a coincidence, the term is:

> Clairvoyant

Defined as:

> A person who claims to have a supernatural ability to perceive events in the future or beyond normal sensory contact. [Google]

To be used as:

> My child is **a clairvoyant**.

And usable as an adjective:

> My child has been exhibiting **clairvoyance**, they are **clairvoyant**.

---

If you mean it in the sense that they have had dreams which turned out to happen, and they are ignoring the ones that didn't - the term is:

> Confirmation bias

Defined as:

> The tendency to interpret new evidence as confirmation of one's existing beliefs or theories.

To be used as:

> My child had another dream that turned out to be real the other day. They are getting scared because they don't notice the dreams that don't come true - they are exhibiting **confirmation bias**.

Answer (score -3):

The *feeling* that this has happened is called a "deja vu."

Comment: I like it, but I notice that more than just the feeling difference, it's kind of reversed too. Deja vu is the feeling that you've done something **before**.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely right. I've corrected it. Although I don't know how you would *know* that this has happened until the deja vu stage!

Comment: Sorry, it's still not correct. I think it would be best to just delete this answer. Déjà vu is slightly related in that it also seems to mix past, present and future in an uncanny way, but it's subjectively associated with *less* information traveling between the times. ("If I have been in this precise situation before, how come I don't remember when that was?")

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. Deja vu has a specific meaning that does not even loosely match the sensation the OP describes. Alexander has either misunderstood the meaning of deja vu or has misunderstood the question

Comment: Deja vu is only the feeling that something has happened previously. It may not have actually happened. In any case, this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: If one sees something happening that one believes to have dreamed about before the feeling in that situation could be appropriately described as "déjà vu", but as the others here point out this is quite different from precognition, claiming to be a prophet or otherwise recipient of a vision of the future or actually believing to have predicted something.

Comment: I guess technical term for what I was thinking of is "déjà rêvé", i.e. "already dreamed", does that make more sense @HansAdler?

Comment: @DarrenH "Doesn't even loosely" both have to do with time, perception, and specific instances. I would consider that a loose connection right there. Sure, not a STRONG connection though